# Excluding a site from Google Alerts query

Tags: google-alerts

I've got a google alert setup as follows :

`"Example Company" OR "http://www.example.com/" -site:pinterest.com`

What I'm trying to achieve here is to get an alert for articles/content that:

- Feature "Example Company"
- Feature "http://www.example.com/"
- But I want to exclude pinterest.com results

The above line used to work as I've had it setup for the past 3 years or so, but recently I've started to get loads of Pinterest results, so it seems the Pinterest filter isn't working.

Any ideas why this is/what needs to be updated in my Alerts search query?

Comment: In my experience, Google Alerts breaks fairly regularly. I will wager that in a couple of weeks your query will be working again, without you having done anything and with no explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) page to put together a list of search criteria in an easy way. Then, by clicking **Advanced Search**, it will give you the exact criteria. These results can then be pasted into [Google Alerts](https://www.google.com/alerts) as the search criteria.

You will notice on the page that there is not an option for **-site:**. If this is a recent change on Google's behalf or not, I'm not sure. However the suggestion posted by @pnuts to use `-pinterest` should give you the desired results.

**EDIT**: The following criteria has not returned any results from http://pinterest.com/, however has given results including the text `pinterest` and `http://pinterest.com/`:

[image: Pinterest Google Alerts example]

With that being the case, it's possible that Google has changed something in the way that Alerts work. Likely, if the Alert is re-created, the problem will be resolved.

Although that is not ideal as it does not find the root cause of the problem, it is a viable workaround in the case that Google Alerts change again.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks - just did some more tests and found that, although it's not listed, -site:pinterest.com does work as OP suggested. I'll remove answer. Harder than I thought. :)

Comment: As OP would like it to work. But I have only found as search results. I haven't found a way to accurately test using Alerts. Even typing just "pinterest" as the search results (https://www.google.com/alerts - "Create an alert about...") doesn't show any alerts from pinterest.com.

Comment: @pnuts I've adjusted it to "As it happens" using this criteria: `"Pinterest" "http://pinterest.com" -site:pinterest.com`. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @pnuts Agreed. Unless Alerts behave differently, what OP states should be working correctly.

Comment: After 24 hours with the following criteria, I can confirm that there I have received no alerts from the site http://pinterest.com/, but plenty of alerts for _other_ websites containing the text `pinterest` and `http://pinterest.com/`. Updated answer with these details. It's getting more confusing. :)

Comment: I wonder if Google has changed something. If OP re-creates their alert, it would be interesting to see if it starts working as expected.